# Mathematical representation of ++a

Tags: c++, post-increment, pre-increment

We can define `a++` as

```
a = a + 1;
```

Which is self-explaining that it makes a copy of `a` then adds 1 to it and puts the result in `a`.

But can we define `++a` the same way? Maybe the answer is very simple but I'm  unaware of it.

Comment: If you only care about the value of `a` after the statement has executed, then `a++` and `++a` are the same.  It's the result of the expression that is different but your “definition” doesn't care about that.  I also wouldn't call it “mathematical” because the mathematical formula *a* = *a* + 1 doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Apparently you've switched `a++` and `++a`. It's `++a`, the prefix operator, that can be replaced with `(a = a+1)`. For `a++`, the postfix operator, the expression result is the original value of `a`, and you can't define that as an expression without using another postfix operator.

Comment: For the mathematical view of things you *can* consider `a` as an infinite sequence of values, namely the values at each point in time. But that's not a practical viewpoint for C++ programming.

Answer (score 0):

a++ and ++a have differences in precedence. 
- a++: you evaluate a before a is incremented; 
- ++a: you increment a before it is evaluated or used

Answer (score 0):

The difference is:

```
int a = 1; 
int b = ++a; 
// Now a == 2 and b == 2 

int c = 1; 
int d = c++;
// Now c == 2 and d == 1
```

The difference is in the returned value of the operation.

Comment: Thnks fr the reply ,i knw the difrnce,m nt asking for it,wat m asking is can we show the functionality of ++a with a simple mathematical equation wch doesnt need any wordly xplanation